# Saving an ArrayList of various objects in an efficient way

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-class, abstract

I would like to know how to save an ArrayList of abstract Objects to a file.
So far I only save primitive types or ArrayLists of primitive types by converting them to a comma separated String and storing this with a buffered reader.

But now I have got an ArrayList of Game Elements, which have really different properties and Constructors, so my normal approach won't work. There has to be something nicer than storing each to a file or each type of Object to a file or add plenty of seperator levels.

How do I do this in a nice way?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: what does "abstract object" mean? objects are concrete.

Comment: I mean different classes which inherit from an abstract one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Serialization, there are plenty of tutorials out there so I am not going to post any code:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can not instantiate Abstract Objects so you will need a child class which extends it. Also Abstract class should implement `Serialize`. Then using `ObjectOutputStream` you can directly write `ArrayList` using `writeObject()` method.

Below is the sample application

```
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable {
    public abstract String getValue(); //Just to show value persist
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    String value = null;
    Child(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
// No throws clause here
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //create Arraylist
    ArrayList<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
    parents.add(new Child("test"));
    //store
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("test.txt"));
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(parents);
    objectOutputStream.close();
    //Read back     
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("test.txt"));
    ArrayList<Parent> readObjects = (ArrayList<Parent>)objectInputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println(readObjects.get(0).getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be two.

Depending on what is the usage of the file later.

ANS 1: It you want the object values to be saved temporarily in the file and reload it again from the file, then serialization is the best options.

ANS 2: If the file is output of the program and then you try the below
     option#1: Start each line in the file with the unique object name
               OBJECT1, blue, pink, yellow....
               OBJECT2, rose, dairy, sunflower, cauliflower..
     option#2 instead of the flat file(txt) you can use an apache poi framework to write
              the object in more organised way.